# Issue with passing python function to jinja

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am working on a Flask web app and I am at a point where I want the admin of the site to be able to approve/deny users. The issue I am facing is that I am trying to call Python functions in html/jinja template. Here is a look. [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvLGe.png)

In the user_approval.html file

``

```
<table id="user-approval" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Full Name:</th>
            <th>Address:</th>
            <th>DOB:</th>
            <th>Email:</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        {% for user in users.items %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ user.a_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.a_address }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.a_dob }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.a_email }}</td>
                <td><button id="approve-user-btn" onclick="{{ user_approve }}">approve</button></td>
                <td><button id="deny-user-btn" onclick="{{ user_deny }}">deny</button></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Full Name:</th>
            <th>Address:</th>
            <th>DOB:</th>
            <th>Email:</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

``

I would need to pass the user_id as an argument. I tried to do something like this

`<button id="approve-user-btn" onclick="{{ user_approve(user.id) }}">approve</button>`

Which calls the functions before admin clicks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work, the `onclick` event can be used to run Javascript, but in this case you should rather create a route in Jinja to run Pyton code. You need to add a `<form>` in your HTML too, and in your form you set the target accordingly (using the function `url_for`). Change the button like this too, so it behaves like a submit element:

```
<button id="approve-user-btn" type="submit"...
```

or

```
<input id="approve-user-btn" type="submit"...
```

And probably add a hidden field for the user ID as well. This value will be included in the form (POST) request.